# How to create a TEXTBOX with auto suggestion in VB.NET for windows based application?

Tags: windows, vb.net

I am trying to create a accept User Name in textbox and as additional feature i want to show suggestion to user automatically.
For example if user press "J" he names starting with "J" (present in name table ) should be displayed as drop-down.

Can i do it with TEXTBOX or is there any other simple way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WinForms, simply set:

- [AutoComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode.aspx) mode to the appropriate replacement value
- [AutoCompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx) to CustomSource
- Finally add all your names to the [AutoCompleteCustomSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource.aspx) collection

An example is in the link above.