# WPF Editable ComboBox Text Search Behavior

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, behavior

I have a ComboBox with binded an Entity ObservableCollection on ItemsSource. Like this:

```
Key    Desc1   Desc2
C0001  myDesc  myDesc
D0001  myDesc  myDesc
A0001  myDesc  MyDesc
```

the combobox is so defined:

```
<ComboBox
   IsEditable=True
   DisplayMemberPath="Key"
   SelectedValuePath="Key"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Now I have this problem...

If I type a character on empty editable textbox of combobox, the first element that "startswith" the typed character is matched. So, If I type "C", the selecteditem is the element "C0001"...and I would avoid this!

I would a different search logic that find the selecteditem based on full text typed. In this way:

```
Text Typed        SelectedItem
C                 null
C0                null
C00               null
C000              null
C0001             [C0001, myDesc, myDesc] OK!
```

Is possible? How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour has always been like this for Combos in Windows. If you want to do something like this, you're probably better off with a search field and a pickable list of results.

<strike>Alternatively, the [TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760389/how-to-create-a-textbox-with-auto-suggestion-in-vb-net-for-windows-based-applicat/4760478#4760478) does support different AutoComplete suggestion modes, but you want a dropdown too I'd imagine.</strike> (no, it doesn't).

This [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/wpf/thread/cec1b222-2849-4a54-bcf2-03041efcf304) makes a stab at coupling the two up, it's pretty neat.

Comment: The question is about WPF not Winforms!

Comment: Oh yeah, the textbox for WPF has none of those things... Sorry for confusion there, it's early!

Comment: there isn't a way to expend the ComboBox base ed override search logic for selecteditem?